# How do I see/debug the full source in .vue files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out why I can't see the full source of my .vue files in the chrome debugger. When I click on webpack:// I see the files there like in my project tree, but when I open them it doesn't show the actual source.

The bottom of each file all have a similar line that says `component.options.__file = "src/foldername/foldername/foo.vue"`

I've tried changing my vue.config.js file a lot, but most importantly it contains the line
`config.devtool = 'cheap-module-source-map'`

Also at the bottom of my chrome dev-tools window it says `'source mapped from app.1df89b9.js'`

Here is full vue.config.js block:

````
const CopyModulesPlugin = require('copy-modules-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL,
    configureWebpack:
    config => {
        config.devtool = 'cheap-module-source-map';
        config.plugins = [
        new CopyModulesPlugin({
            destination: 'webpack-modules'
        }),
            ...config.plugins
            ];
            config.module.rules = [
            {
                test: /\shared\.worker\.ts$/,
                loader: 'worker-loader',
                options: {
                    worker: {
                        type: 'SharedWorker',
                        options: {
                            type: 'classic',
                            credentials: 'include',
                            name: 'birdman-shared-worker'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                test: /(?<!\.shared)\.worker\.ts$/,
                loader: 'worker-loader',
                options: {
                    worker: {
                        type: 'Worker'
                        options: {
                            type: 'classic',
                            credentials: 'include',
                            name: 'birdman-worker'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            ...config.module.rules];
    }```
````

Comment: there is several options, see here : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ for the devtool that suits your needs

Comment: Related: If you are not already using Vue.js devtools (example: [Vue.js devtools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd)) try those out. I hardly feel the need to view the source code. Visualizing the components and their data is a big help on its own.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I am on a closed system with very limited access to outside tools so I can't use those plugins for chrome.

Comment: @Lk77 thank you - I tried all of those options with no visible changes to the issue described in the original post.

Comment: So `config.devtool = 'inline-source-map'` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

sometime sources-map file will parse failed. clean the cache and refresh try again.
if it still.change config.devtool value to inline-source-map.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Webpack documentation, [`cheap-module-source-map` are one of the special cases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#special-cases). You should try [one of the recommended values for development](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#development) instead unless you have a special requirement.

Other than that, I briefly check your source map and I think it is working correctly. However, according to [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/146#issuecomment-877869882), you could write some code to make the source map files stand out more:

> For me the source maps were working, but they were just piled in a heap of other files which made it painful to find. This worked for me to filter out the "real" ones from the garbage. My project is set up fairly standard using Vue-CLI, Vue 3, and TypeScript.